# OAuth2 dance with Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am newbie to OAuth2 and understood its implementation theoretically very well. I followed this link to handle OAuth2 callback URL [Build Authorization Callback Handler](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/oauth-authorization-callback-handler/). But i am using Spring Security in my project, so i don't have to do much work myself. I am using salesforce API. Whenever there is *UserRedirectionRequiredException*, the spring security OAuth2's *ClientContextFilter* handles it and redirects for authorization.It all works very Well. I am able to get contacts , tags from salesforce account using RestTemplate and salesfore Resource.
         The question is how to handle oauth2 callback URL using spring security. whenever i call any salesforce api e.g getContacts, if access token is available it works. But if i don't have accesstoken, the user is redirected and when authorized, the access Token is obtained from provider but the control goes to my Oauth2callback url and finishes there. Now i have again to call the getContacts Api and it retrives the contacts.

Help me in implementing OAuth2Callback URL using spring security so that when i call any Api, if unauthorized, after authorizing and retrieving accesstoken it automatically calles back to that API rather than stoping on my OAuth2callback URL.