# Getting rid of code/state URI parameters when using OAuth2RestTemplate

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have built a simple Spring Boot application that acts as an OAuth 2.0 client using the `@EnableOAuth2Client` annotation. My application is creating an `OAuth2RestTemplate` and the OAuth dance succeeds nicely.

The problem is that when I access my application e.g. at `http://localhost:8080/someRequest` (where the method serving this resource uses the `OAuth2RestTemplate#getObject` method to retrieve some remote resources, I end up with sth. like `http://localhost:8080/someRequest?code=ABC&state=DEF` in my browser.

Is there a way to get rid of these parameters using some Spring configuration magic or do I have to do that myself? I saw that the sample Tonr application suffers from the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that you have to handle the callback url that u have registered with OAuth2 provider. when you transfer code and state parameter to the provider Server for access token and refresh token, the provider sends request back to ur callback URL with access token. In callback URL u now have to check if access token is available, you redirect to the original request(u need to save original request before OAuth2 dance).
   I know  this stuff theoretically, but didnot find Spring-Security-OAuth2 example for handling the callback URL.
   I asked same question, but didnot get any answer.
[OAuth2 Dance With Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33095213/oauth2-dance-with-spring-security)
   However without using spring security, i found one link which shows handling callback url manually.It will help u in understanding the flow.
   [Google Handle callback URl](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/oauth-authorization-callback-handler)
   If u found any example of spring secrity handling callback url , Share with me.
     I found this as an issue with spring security oAuth2. Check this [JIRA Issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/137)